# Does any sequence in Hilbert space have biorthogonal sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In a Hilbert space $H$, If we define $\{y_n\}$ as $y_{n}=\frac{x_{n}}{\left\|x_{n}\right\|^2} \text { for } n=m \text { and } y_{n}=0 \text { for } n \neq m$, then for any $\{x_n\}\in H$ ,$\{y_n\}$ is a biorthogonal sequence of $\{x_n\}$, is that correct?

Comment: What is $m$ in your definition?

Comment: n and m are just natural numbers

Comment: I'm trying to find$
\left\{y_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { in } H
$such that $
\left\langle x_{m}, y_{n}\right\rangle=\delta_{m n} \text { for all } m, n \in \mathbb{N}
$

Comment: Your definition does not make sense. $y_n$ should not depend on $m$>

Comment: So $
y_n
$ has to be a function of $x_n$?

Comment: You cannot construct a biorthogonal sequence associated to an *arbitrary* sequence. At the very least you need that $x_n \neq x_m$ if $n \neq m$.

Comment: By your definition as stated here, $y_n = 0$ for all $n$ except $n=m$. $m$ is a constant in your definition, not a variable. Will a sequence that is all $0$s except for a single entry be biorthogonal?